# Jquery slider not responsive - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm putting together a responsive WordPress website but seem to be stuck when it comes to the slider. I think it's conflicting with something on my site, because the default theme (http://wordpress.org/themes/intuition) has a responsive slider.

This is the script I'm using:

```
//SLIDESHOW
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//HOMEPAGE SLIDES
jQuery('.slider-slides').cycle({
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 4000,
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    next: '.slider-next', 
    prev: '.slider-prev',
    pager: '.slider-pages',
    pause: true,
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    containerResize: false,
    slideResize: false,
    fit: 1
}); 
jQuery('.slider-prev, .slider-next').click(function(){
    jQuery('.slider-slides').cycle('pause');
});
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 500)
        jQuery('#toplink').addClass('active');
    else
        jQuery('#toplink').removeClass('active');
});
}); 
function slide_resize(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
var ht = jQuery(this).height();
jQuery(this).parent().animate({height: ht}); 
}
```

I tried changing the resize options to true, but nothing changed. I tried adding width: 100% and height: 450px to the code as was suggested elsewhere, but that didn't change anything either.

I'm really at my wits end! If anyone has any suggestions, that'd be amazing. Thank you!

Here's my header.php:

```
<?php if(cpotheme_get_option('cpo_slider_always') == 1 || is_front_page()){ ?>
        <?php $feature_args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
        'meta_key' => 'page_featured',
        'meta_value' => 'slider',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'order' => 'ASC'); ?>
        <?php $slider_posts = new WP_Query($feature_args); ?>
        <?php if($slider_posts->post_count > 0): $slide_count = 0; ?>
        <div id="slider" class="slider">
            <ul class="slider-slides">
                <?php while($slider_posts->have_posts()): $slider_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $slide_count++; ?>
                <?php $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), array(1500, 7000), false, ''); ?>
                <?php $slide_position = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'slide_position', true); ?>
                <li id="slide_<?php echo $slide_count; ?>" class="slide slide-<?php echo $slide_position; ?>" style="background:url(<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>) no-repeat center; background-size:cover;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="slide-textbox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h2 class="slide-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <div class="slide-content"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php if($slider_posts->post_count > 1): ?>
            <div class='slider-prev'></div>
            <div class='slider-next'></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>  
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php }else{ ?>

        <?php $header_image = get_header_image(); if($header_image != ''): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $header_image; ?>" class="header-image" />
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Well for starters the resize function slide_resize would need to be bound to an event watching the display size. Right now, from what I can tell, nothing is calling the function at all.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm quite new to jquery, do you know how I'd go about calling the function? Would it help if I showed you what I have in my header.php? Thank you! Edit - Added my header.php, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have `slide_resize` bound to anything. The function exists, but it's not called anywhere. If by chance you do have it called somewhere else that you didn't show:

The "slider" itself and the "slides" themselves shrink to be mobile responsive (width at least). You just have the height of the slider to worry about, not the images themselves. Something like this should do the trick (sorry for syntax errors):

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
    var currentWidth = jQuery('.slider-slides .container').width();
    var newHeight = currentWidth / 2.444; //2.444 is your 1100/450 from the full size slider
    ('.slider-slides .container').height(newHeight); //Container height
    jQuery('.slider-slides .slide').height(newHeight); // Slide wrap's height
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure whether or not I have it called anywhere. I'm quite new to this side of things. Would it help if I post what I have in my header.php, where the slider gets called up? Edit - Added the header code.

Comment: Try adding `jQuery('.slider-slides').slide_resize();` to the bottom of you javascript

Comment: Otherwise, add the code I wrote to the bottom of it, it should handle the height of it for you (width already works)

Comment: Wonderful! If that helped, would you mind accepting the answer? :)